# A Free, Rich Text Editor like CKEditor is required but it must be Content Security Policy i.e. CSP complaint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor, rich-text-editor, content-security-policy

Could you all please help me in looking for a Rich Text Editor a bit like CKEditor. However, it must be CSP complaint unlike CKEditor.
I have been using CKEditor for a long time in my application but now after introducing CSP (report only), browser shows CSP exceptions while loading ckeditor.

Now, we are looking to find anyother editor or to find a work around. Unable to find any workarounds yet. As their devs say that they can't provide any solution to this problem. 
Here is the link: https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8584

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
 [image]

Comment: What does CSP compliant mean to you? Adding the `'unsafe-inline'` keyword to your default-src (or script-src) could be a workaround.

Comment: We need to use CSP to its fullest. Adding 'unsafe-inline' is never a solution for us...
We must look n find a component which is fully complaint with CSP.

Comment: @ChFaizanMustansar did you find a solution for this?